# Swift access dictionary value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Rails api that I am using to develop my iOS application with. I am currently using alamofire to perform HTTP requests and am running into an issue when trying to access dictionary keys.

Type of the response from Alamofire is `__NSDictionaryI`.

```
AF.request("\(url)/wishlist", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
            case .success(let res):
                print(type(of: res))
                print(res["message"])
            }
        }
```

I am coming from Ruby where we access hash keys like `hash["key"]` but am running into issues when trying to do that here. The response from this request prints

```
{
    message = "Care was created";
    status = ok;
}
```

I was hoping I could do `res["message"]` to access that value to pass to a toast message. However, I am unable to compile due to the following error

> Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

Can anybody explain what is happening here and why I am unable to capture this value?

Comment: Swift is quite restrictive with regard to types. Retrieving a value from a dictionary returns `Any` – the most unspecified type in Swift – , you are responsible to cast the value to the expected type. Or use `responseDecodable` and parse the JSON into an appropriate data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step should be to learn Swift and forget about any assumptions into which Ruby may have led you. Ruby and Swift are opposites. Ruby has no typing ("duck typing") and any variable can adopt any value. Swift has strict typing and a variable must declare its type at the outset and can never change that type.

You can supply a type by casting the response result to a definite type. For instance, you might cast it to `[String:Any]`. That's a dictionary (similar to Ruby hash) and can be subscripted.

It would be better, however, to *decode* the response content into a struct with a `message` property and `status` property, each of those being properly typed, rather than settling for the typeless `responseJSON`. You shouldn't say `Any` unless you really have to, and you rarely have to.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here, but I have a `Response` type with a message and code of type string and int. `case .success(let res as? Response):` gives me this error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. A bit frustrating because it seems like whatever I try is not working. However, I am still getting used to typed languages so my ignorance here is palpable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alamofire+swift+decodable+struct And see vadian's comment suggesting that you use `responseDecodable` rather than `responseJSON`.